# write like query using cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli, cqlsh

How to write the like query in cassandra.

```
select * from user where user_name like '%abcd%'
```

How to write it into CQL(Cassandra query language)

Because i have to search some content base on keyword.

Comment: As far as i know cassandra does not support like query operation. Because we have to query from more node so it maily suport EQ or IN on index columns family.

Comment: I have required search on the keyword. If you have know about this please help me

Comment: Use elastic search or Apache solr  with cassandra. This are best tool for real time keyword search with long string or text.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be real-time, you could use [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/) or [Shark](http://shark.cs.berkeley.edu/).  This enables you to run exactly the query you're speaking about.  If you use DSE it works out of the box with Hive.  If not, you'll want to check out [this Hive driver](https://github.com/tuplejump/cash).

To get this working with open source Cassandra, you'll need:

1. HDFS running co-located with your Cassandra nodes
2. If you use Spark, you'll need Spark workers (ideally co-located as well, though this isn't a hard requirement)
3. Hive or Shark running on a machine that can access the cluster

Comment: Please share the link where we can configure the both on same platform then run the query.

Comment: But it don't take example with cassandra with run the query